# I am trying to make a generic method in c# where I want to return a list of records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, automapper

```
class Employee
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

class ServiceIEmployeeModel
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Above Employee and `ServiceIEmployeeModel` class should auto mapped for its view representation.

```
//My Generic Method below
public List<U> ListMapping<T, U>(List<T> sourceClass)
{           
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<T, U>(); });
            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            List<U> finalData = mapper.Map<List<T>, List<U>>(sourceClass);
            return finalData;
}

List<Employee> employeeData = new List<Employee>();
List<ServiceIEmployeeModel> obj = new List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>();

  ServiceIEmployeeModel obj = new ServiceIEmployeeModel();
  obj.Id = 2;
  obj.Name = "xyz";       

employeeData =
ListMapping<List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>, List<Employee>>(sourceClass:obj);
```

I am trying to make a generic method in c# where I want to return a list of records.

I have the following code to call the generic method:

> ```
> But i get an error saying :-
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>'
>  to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>>' 
> Msc.MasterData.Presentation.Web   C:\Users\sabarimani.a\Desktop\Presentation.Web\Web\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs    59
>   Active
> ```

Comment: I just want to note that it's a very bad idea to create the mapping every time when you map the classes. It should be done only once, and then inject the mapper with DI. Or otherwise use the static Mapper for mapping objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ListMapping` method accepts type parameters and tries to map *list of that types*. Pay attention to this line:

```
List<U> finalData = mapper.Map<List<T>, List<U>>(sourceClass);
```

When you pass `List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>` and `List<Employee>` as type parametets to this method then, `T` will be `List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>` and `U` will be `List<Employee>` type and your `List<U> finalData = mapper.Map<List<T>, List<U>>(sourceClass);`  line will be actually like:

```
List<List<Employee>> finalData = mapper
    .Map<List<List<ServiceIEmployeeModel>>, List<List<Employee>>>(sourceClass);
```

And this is not what you want to achieve. Instead call this method like:

```
List<ServiceIEmployeeModel> initialData = .....;
employeeData =
    ListMapping<ServiceIEmployeeModel, Employee>(initialData);
```

Comment: I have replaced List parameters with Class as commented and it works. Thank you.